# How do I dynamically generate a file name in python?

Tags: python, macos, pip, plist

We're working on a python application for MAC OSX that should be pip-installable, and we want to automate the creation of a `plist` file during installation, but the **file name** must contain the OSX username in order for the application to work, eg. `com.username.app.plist`.

Q : How do I dynamically generate such a file in python ?

Comment: Are you just looking to get the username from OSX?

Comment: I'm looking to create a file that contains the OSX username in it's name, like `com.steven.app.plist`, as of now, we should manually create the file in order for the app to work, we want to automate this task on installation !

Comment: Which is the part you're having trouble with, getting the username or concatenating the strings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you just need the username:

```
import getpass
user = getpass.getuser()
fname = "com.strange.things." + user + ".more.strange.things"
```

Comment: that solved my problem, thanks !